# What is a "distinguished subset"?

Tags: terminology

I don't know if this is another word for something I already know or if it is something altogether different. I'm reading my textbook in CS about distributed algorithms, and this came up.

I googled for a definition but couldn't find one.

> The state set $Q$ contains a distinguished subset of initial states.

Comment: Maybe it would be more appropriate for StackOverflow or the like.

Comment: It looked like a math term, so I figured I'd try here first. We'll see what others say.

Comment: After all, there is a computer science tag here, so why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A distinguished subset is one that is chosen out of all the subsets.  In this case, some of the states are chosen to be "initial states".

Answer (score 2):

It just means a particular subset that we're going to pay special attention to. It does not mean that the subset has any special properties.